# How to assign a random value to opacity key in PostScript phase rather than TeX phase?

Tags: pstricks

I want to have a random opacity but I don't want to use `fp` package. Shortly speaking, is it possible to pass PostScript expression to `opacity`?

Here is the minimal not-working example to save your time.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psframe*[linecolor=gray,opacity={!Rand}](2,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Warning !

`Rand` had been tacitly modified from its original behavior (producing a random real number between 0 and 0.5 inclusive) to a new behavior (producing a random real number between 0 and 1 inclusive). If you are new to `Rand`, it is good; no code needs to be updated in your existing code.

Comment: This *may* start with a redefinition of how `opacity` is store. For example, `\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{opacity}[1]{\pst@checknum{#1}\psk@opacityalpha }` should not include a `\pst@checknum` and directly store the content in `\pst@opacityalpha`, for insertion in postscript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very easy way is to define a new key, which uses its arguments as Postscript code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\makeatletter
\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{psopacity}[1]{%
  \edef\psk@opacityalpha{#1 }%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,2)
  \psset{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red, linestyle=none, linewidth=0pt}
  \multido{\ra=0+0.5,\rb=0.5+0.5}{11}{%
    \psframe[psopacity=Rand](\ra,0)(\rb,2)}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is _not_ a good idea to set the same internal macro by two different optional arguments.

Comment: @Herbert Generally speaking you are right, but I don't see any problem here. Another way would be to locally redefine `\tx@setTransparency` with `\pst@def{setTransparency}< Rand .setopacityalpha >`, but that may be less comfortable. Or one could use `\patchcmd` to redefine the `opacity` key definition.

Comment: no, redefining `\pst@checknum` ist the only _safe_ way.

Comment: @Herbert So how would you change `\pst@checknum` to affect only the `opacity` key without changing `pstricks.tex`?

Comment: the simple way is to have a precheck of the `opacity` argument or, the better way, to use `pstricks.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks/  :-)

Comment: @Herbert Hey, you're cheating :)

Comment: @Herbert: Access denied: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8osz6.png

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to pass a postscript expression to define the opacity, however it does not directly use the PSTricks `opacity` option. Instead the Ghostscript/Postscript operator `.setshapealpha` can be used used. (See [Ghostscript additional operators](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Language.htm#Additional_operators)).

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\myRandomOpacity{\pst@Verb{Rand .setshapealpha}}
\def\myResetOpacity{\pst@Verb{1.0 .setshapealpha}}
\makeatother


\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linecolor=red,unit=4cm](-1,-1)(1,1)
  \psdot(! 0 Rand)
  \psdot(! 0 Rand)
  \myRandomOpacity
  \psframe*[linecolor=green](0,0)(1,1)%
  \myRandomOpacity
  \psframe*[linecolor=green](0,0)(1,-1)
  \myRandomOpacity
  \psframe*[linecolor=green](0,0)(-1,-1)
  \myRandomOpacity
  \psframe*[linecolor=green](0,0)(-1,1)  
  \myResetOpacity
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The `.setshapealpha` is also used internally by PSTricks. Indeed pst-news08 states: `pstricks supports transparent colors with Ghostscript’s .setopacityalpha,
.setblendmode, and .setshapealpha. These functions are not
known to VTEX or Adobes Distiller. The optional argument vtex
disables transparencies and distiller overrides the Ghostscript
functions with the ones from the Distiller.`

Here is the result of the MWE:

[image: result of the MWE]